# nosetests: --nologcapture still captures INFO messages

Tags: python, nose, python-unittest, nosetests

With the code

```
import unittest
import logging

class LoggingTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_that_logs(self):
        logging.warning("Hello")
        logging.info("World")
        for a in xrange(100000000000000000):
            pass
```

I get this unexpected output:

```
$ nosetests --version
nosetests version 1.3.7
$ nosetests log_from_nosetest.py --nocapture --nologcapture
WARNING:root:Hello
^C
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 105.376s

OK
```

As can be seen. The WARNING log level message is printed, but not the INFO level one.

I've tried using the `--logging-level` [setting](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#extended-usage) but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a missing feature. If --nologcapture is set, nose simply ignores all logging setup, e.g. --logging-level is not used at all. You can remedy that with a

`logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)`

in your code - not sure if that's what you want, because this kind of setup shouldn't be in library-code at all. It would be fine within the test-setup though.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default log level is warning. Set it with

```
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.INFO)
```